# How to sum value of the same products according to the year they were sold?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, sumifs

I have an excel sheet with the list of all the products sold in different years. I need to display separately the total price of the each product that was sold in 2016 only:

[image]

and I need to get all the prices of the products sold in 2016 ( for each product separately) and create a new table like this

[image]

So if there are 100 laptops sold over the years, I need to create a new table with total price of the sold laptops in 2016.

I tried to achieve this by using sumif, but I can't figure out how to write correct condition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add anothercolumn to identify the year sold, e.g =year(a2).  Create a pivot and filter on the new column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SUMIFS formula that escaped you.

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$A$2:$A$8,">"&DATE(G$1,1,0),$A$2:$A$8,"<"&DATE(G$1,12,32),$B$2:$B$8,F3)
```

In the picture below it is in cell F3 from where it can be copied down.

[image]

By simply changing the year in G1 you can get the results for different years. So, you could create a list of all items with a column for each year and see the results side by side.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I applied this function, but when I copy down year cell changes from G1 to G2, G3 and etc. in the function and because of that function doesn't work. And I'm not able to display products' names in the Product section, only total sold is being displayed under 2016. Is there a way to display names also for each product? Because there're about 1000+ products and it's not possible to write them one by one.

Comment: `G$1` doesn't change to G2, G3, G4 etc. Please make sure you copy the $-signs correctly. It's possible to copy1000 product names with a few clicks. You could then filter the complete list to hide all rows with 0 volume.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for finding the `SUM` for all products depending on the `DATE`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(YEAR(A:A); 2016*{or your reference cell}*; C:C))
```

The formula for finding the `SUM` from both `DATE` and `CATEGORY`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(C:C; YEAR(A:A); 2016 *{or your reference cell}*; B:B; "laptop" *{or your reference cell}*))
```

It won't work without `ARRAYFORMULA` and be careful with quotes,